# Google Staticmap 403 error

Tags: javascript, maps

while using staticmaps I always get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

but I have no idea why. I think my markup is correct but I think you guys can help me.

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE&zoom=15&size=160x90&markers=color:red|LATITUDE|LONGITUDE&key=KEY">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://maps-generator.com/ this would guide you very well , and i think the new map uses api key , that site would guide through out

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE&zoom=15&size=160x90&markers=color:red|LATITUDE|LONGITUDE&key=KEY">
```

So where it says `KEY` you are supposed to put your API key.  You can generate one here: https://console.cloud.google.com

You need to find Google Maps Static.  Select it, enable it.  Go to credentials and create an API key.  Then I would advise you to limit the API key by domain (http referrer) using the following URLs.

`*.YOURDOMAN.COM/*`

`YOURDOMAIN.COM/*`

One in each box.  Replace YOURDOMAIN.COM with your website address.  I hope that helps.

You also need to replace LATITUDe, LONGDITUDE with the correct values.  The easiest way to find them is to do a Google Maps search and copy the URL.  They look something like:

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Square+Balloon/@51.613498,0.0882521,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xec92c9ffe1ab887d!8m2!3d51.613498!4d0.0882521

The part you need is after the @ sign.

`@51.613498,0.0882521`

51.613498 is the Latitude and
0.0882521 is the Longitude.

Incidentally the other part after the Z is the Zoom.  Which you can see in your URL as zoom=15.  You can zoom in and out and copy that value too if you want.